# Debug a crash in _dispatch_client_callout in crash reports from macOS App Store

Tags: macos, crash, grand-central-dispatch

I have crashes coming in via XCode's Organizer format he App Store. The crashes do not seem to reference any of *my* code and they seem relatively consistent. Im not sure how to figure out where the issue is since nothing int he stack traces seems to directly implicate my code. Only one StringByReplacingOccurencesOfString seems to be listed in the latest crash, but not in previous similar ones (See last image):

[image: Xcode Info]

I am not sure how to dig in here and get more detail since the symbolicated crash report does not seem to give me any real detail to go on.

Here are the other thread states:

[image: Other threads]

Last version crashes:

[image]

Comment: Is there really nothing but stack traces? Usually the console or crash report includes some additional diagnostic information. (It may seem cryptic, but might be useful.) Or if you go over to the “errors” tab in the navigator and tap on the “runtime errors”, there might be something there...

Comment: FWIW, I’ve seen this sort of cryptic stack trace if there’s something going on buried in GCD (e.g., you’ve got some thread explosion with too many `async` calls to a concurrent queue and have exhausted the limited 64 worker threads that are available, etc.). You’ll generally not see your code in the stack trace (because it’s in the middle of GCD queue processing, not in your code). I’m not saying that’s the problem here (because we don’t have your GCD related code), but it’s the class of problem that you’ll probably should be looking for...